# How to extract ROI from an binary image using GrabCut segmentation algorithm

Tags: python, opencv

I am doing a zebra crossing detection project. Where as a part of pre-processing I have converted zebra corssing images into binary images.

[Binary image of zebra crossing:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EqZwx.png)

Now I want to extract zebra crossing area as ROI using GrabCut segmentation algorithm. But I can not find a good solution. One thing might be done that , as zebra crossing is a rectangular shape then it might be possible to find 4 corner point of that rectangular shaped zebra crossing. Using that 4 corner point and using this function it might be possible to do segmentaion of zebra crossing area. But I don't know how to do this.

```
rect = (50,50,450,290)
cv.grabCut(img,mask,rect,bgdModel,fgdModel,5,cv.GC_INIT_WITH_RECT)
```

please anyone suggest me to how can i do this task?

Comment: Can you post a link to the original image before you did any processing. Also best to show all your code as there may be better ways to binarize.

Comment: I think for detecting zebra crossing areas, morphological solutions not a good way to use.